# Sumifs Formula Wth Value Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have data table of a questionnaire from google that I made and downloded as an excel file. I am trying to sum the answers by multiple criteria with `sumifs` formula. The numbers of the questions in the table in Main Worksheet is in the first row from cell "D1":
[image]

i want to sum the results to each question by the number of the qustion and another column criteria of people who marked yes and no. for example, I want to know what is the total points that I got to the question just from the people who are marked as `yes` in `column C` in this table in Total Worksheet:

[image]

here is my formula that is not working

```
=SUMIFS(Main!C3:C30,Main!$B$3:$B$31,"Yes",Main!$C$1:$AK$1,Total!B14)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SUMIFS to handle this problem, as you've posted it.  If your Sum criteria was supposed to be based off the details in the Department Column and the Yes/No column, then a SUMIFS formula would work fine for establishing those multiple criteria.  I reworked the sheet to put the Department into Column A, and the Yes/No into Column B, with the values for the first question under Column C.

The following formula works for me:

```
=SUMIFS(C3:C11,B3:B11,"Yes",A3:A11,"QA")
```

Where C3:C11 is the range being summed.  I would then repeat this formula changing only the Column range to each question I wanted to sum.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I wanted some formula that  I would not have to change the sum range 35 times for each question. I wanted the one of the criteria would be based on the question number

Comment: I think this problem would be more easily solved using a pivot table.  The question numbers/titles would be the columns, and then you could use the "Yes/No" criteria in the rows.  You could also filter by department if your work requires you to do that.